# Doctrine 2 + cyrillic

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am trying to read an utf8 (cyrillic) data from database with Doctrine2 ORM, but it always returns unreadable symbols.

My database, table and text field in utf8-general-ci.
The connection looks like this:

```
$em = EntityManager::create(array(
  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
  'unix_socket' => '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'host' => DB_HOST,
  'user' => DB_USER,
  'password' => DB_PASS,
  'dbname' => DB_NAME
  ), $config);
```

But still without success. How can I solve it?
Thank you

Comment: whats inside the database? what does phpmyadmin show?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin shows the valid readable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I've found and it works:

```
$em = EntityManager::create(array(
  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
  'unix_socket' => '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'host' => DB_HOST,
  'user' => DB_USER,
  'password' => DB_PASS,
  'dbname' => DB_NAME
  ), $config);
$em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(new MysqlSessionInit('utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci'));
```